# Select range of elements in XQuery 3.0

Tags: basex, xquery-3.0

I have the following xml data structure

```
<journey>
<leg origin='a' dest='b' />
<leg origin='b' dest='c' />
<leg origin='c' dest='d' />
<leg origin='d' dest='e' />
<leg origin='e' dest='f' />
... and so on
</journey>
```

I want to select `leg` elements from `origin='b'` to `dest='e'`

I have tried using a tumbling window, following-sibling, but can only seem to match the first and last elements with nothing in between.

I am using XQuery 3.0 in BaseX 8.6

Comment: Please add a query that shows what you have tried so far. Additionally, describe what "from origin to dest" means exactly. The title of your question seems to indicate that you are looking for minimum and maximum values, whereas the example might indicate that you are trying to find paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As not all scope conditions have been given in the initial question, I am offering several answers. All of them are based on the same query prolog and the following assumptions (and probably some others):

- the searched origin and destination exist
- all origins & destinations occur only once
- there are no cycles (e.g. `b` → `c` → `b`)

### Query prolog

```
declare variable $JOURNEY :=
  <journey>
    <leg origin='a' dest='b' />
    <leg origin='b' dest='c' />
    <leg origin='c' dest='d' />
    <leg origin='d' dest='e' />
    <leg origin='e' dest='f' />
  </journey>;
declare variable $ORIGIN := 'b';
declare variable $DEST := 'e';
```

### Using a tumbling window

Assumption: The destination occurs after the origin.

```
for tumbling window $legs in $JOURNEY/leg
    start $s when $s/@origin = $ORIGIN
    end   $e when $e/@dest   = $DEST
return $legs
```

### Using following-sibling

Assumption, same here: The destination occurs after the origin.

```
let $origin := $JOURNEY/leg[@origin = $ORIGIN]
let $dest := $JOURNEY/leg[@dest = $DEST]
return (
  $origin,
  $origin/following-sibling::leg[. << $dest],
  $dest
)
```

### Using node comparisons

Assumption, same here: The destination occurs after the origin.

```
let $origin := $JOURNEY/leg[@origin = $ORIGIN]
let $dest := $JOURNEY/leg[@dest = $DEST]
return $JOURNEY/leg[
  . is $origin or
  . >> $origin and . << $dest or
  . is $dest
]
```

### Recursive approach

Assumption: Order is not guaranteed.

```
declare function local:trace(
  $leg      as element(leg),
  $journey  as element(journey),
  $end      as xs:string
) as element(leg)* {
  $leg,
  for $dest in $leg/@dest[. != $end]
  return local:trace($journey/leg[@origin = $dest], $journey, $end)
};
local:trace($JOURNEY/leg[@origin = $ORIGIN], $JOURNEY, $DEST)
```